# USB input to 2 devices

Tags: usb

I have a laptop and a desktop, bothof which I want to share a keyboard and a mouse.  Only one will be on at a time, but I have some female --> 2 male usb cables.  I was hoping they would be preferable for ease of use when switching between the two computers.  I tried the setup, and so far it work, but only with my laptop, which is running linux.  When I do the switch over to my windows desktop, it power is in the devices (caps lock and the mouse light up), but the actual devices won't work.  Thank you so much.

Comment: That's not how USB works. Those USB split cables you describe only split the power, there's no way for a USB cable to split the data between two different USB hosts. What you really want is called a `KVM switch`.

Comment: Or more simply a USB switch, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00FEM3OKM

Comment: @duskwuff   Interesting.. you should give the title in case the link ever went down. That "Tek Republic TUS-200 USB Sharing Switch - 2 Port Manual Switch One USB Device/Hub Between Two Computers"  Is interesting... A related thing is a KVM switch, many now might support USB.. so that would work. And a related thing to that is a reverse kvm switch, allowing multiple consoles(keyboard monitor, mouse), for one computer..  But the device you mention looks very much to be the thing he's looking for.

Comment: Here is an explanation how it is (should be) done, http://superuser.com/questions/1128633/is-there-a-difference-between-these-types-of-usb-switches/1128638#1128638    and another example, http://superuser.com/questions/1128622/pc-switcher-for-usb-hubs/1128632#1128632